# How can I make the delete buttons fully functional with right ID using php, AJAX or MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having a little problem with this, every delete button is supposed to delete the record of its own id. If we click 164 it must delete the record of 164. It works fine if I remove the ajax and ask the form to validate directly, but if I use AJAX it only deletes the record of 1st record regardless of what button I press e.g. in current scenario it will always delete the record of 159 even if I press 164 button. My code gives the following output: Remember it works fine if I ask the form to validate directly from other PHP file.
[This is my output please have a look at it. Its quite simple!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZqNb.jpg)

```
if(is_numeric($lumens) && $lumens < 5000 && $lumens >250){

if(is_numeric($THD) && $THD <= 20 && $THD  >=0){

    if(is_numeric($scaled_power_factor) && $scaled_power_factor >=0.9){

        if(is_numeric($scaled_cct) && $scaled_cct <=5700){

            if(is_numeric($scaled_cri) && $scaled_cri >=65){

                if(is_numeric($scaled_input_power)){




                    $con = new mysqli(localhost, asd, myp, rec);
                    if(!$con){

                        echo "Couldn't connect to the database";
                    }
                    else{
                        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

                        $query = "INSERT INTO scaling_performance_data SET
                            MODEL_NUMBER = '$model_number',
                            LUMENS = '$lumens',
                            scaled_luminaire_efficacy = '$lm_w',
                            scaled_input_power = '$scaled_input_power',
                            THD = '$THD',
                            SCALED_POWER_FACTOR = '$scaled_power_factor',
                            SCALED_CCT = '$scaled_cct',
                            SCALED_CRI = '$scaled_cri',
                            HOUSING_VARIATION = '$housing_variation',
                            user_id = '$id'
                            ";
                        if($con->query($query)){

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM scaling_performance_data WHERE user_id='$id';";
                            $result = $con->query($sql);
                            if($result){
                                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){




                                        ?>
                                        <form>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>adsf</th><th>adsf</th><th>adsf</th><th>adsf</th><th>adsf</th><th>adsf</th><th><input type="button" name ="delete_id" id="delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" onclick="vlid();"/></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                function vlid(){

                                                    var delete_id = $('#delete_id').val();
                                                    alert(delete_id);
                                                    $.post('validator.php',{

                                                            postdelete_id : delete_id

                                                        },
                                                        function(data){

                                                            $('#del').html(data);

                                                        }
                                                    )
                                                }

                                            </script>
                                        </form>

                                    <?php

                                    }
                                }
```

validator.php is:

```
$id = $_POST['postdelete_id'];

$con = new mysqli(localhost, asd, myp, rec); 
if(!$con){

    echo "Couldn't connect to the database";
}
else{

    $query="DELETE FROM scaling_performance_data WHERE ID='$id';";

    if($con->query($query)){
        echo "Your Result was deleted successful";
        echo $id;

    }else{

        echo "There was a problem Please try again later";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var delete_id = $(event.target).val();` instead of: `var delete_id = $('#delete_id').val();`

Comment: Yes. I tried it exactly the way you suggested me right now. It does not even get the value by doing so. After the code I've typed alert(delete_id) to make sure that it gets the right ID. Thank you for you help but it didn't work.

Comment: Updated, you should use `$(event.target)` not `$(this)`, sorry my bad. I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: It was pretty helpful. Thank you! You solved my problem. Well Now I want to the record to vanish or disappear instantly when they are deleted without refreshing the page. Can you help me with that?
It is 100% fine to say "No" if you're busy or uninterested.

Comment: Just re-use the same element and call: `$(event.target).closest('tr').hide();` to hide whole row.

Comment: You're genius. You solved my problem with a single common line. I've described the same question on several places like facebook and quora. I am getting so weird answers that I started scratching my head. It was so easy, so simple and people have been suggesting me to code several more pages. You've my undying gratitude for your help. I'll keep you in mind for other questions though. And I can't upvote your answer sorry. Don't have good reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

1st ID must be unique so use

```
class="delete_id"
```

instead of

```
id="delete_id"
```

2nd remove `onclick="vlid();"`  and use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.delete_id',function(){
       var getValue = parseInt($(this).val());
       $.post('validator.php',{postdelete_id : getValue},function(data){
          $('#del').html(data);
       });
    });
});
```

and to remove the tr which deleted use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click','.delete_id',function(){
          var thisBtn = $(this);
          var getValue = parseInt(thisBtn .val());
           $.post('validator.php',{postdelete_id : getValue},function(data){
              $('#del').html(data);
              thisBtn.closest('tr').remove();
           });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your vlid() function, JQuery is only selecting the first element with id = delete_id. I would try passing the ID to the vlid() function like this:

```
<input type="button" ... onclick="vlid(<?php echo $row['ID'];?>)"/>
```

And then modify your vlid() function to accept the ID parameter.